# TCL: lsearch from line when you have "-" string failed

Tags: tcl

I have the following line:

```
109081011 0.50456 "sun"- bar      r     03/12/2023 09:57:48 MASTER
```

I want to use lsearch command to find if name exists.
For that I' using the below command:

```
lsearch -exact -regexp [lindex $line 0] mx\[0-9\]
```

But failed on the "-" string in the $line

> Error: list element in quotes followed by "-" instead of space
> Use error_info for more info. (CMD-013)

Can someone advice how to overcome?

Comment: Try to replace the " characters to something else before doing lsearch. For example, set line [string map [list \" @] $line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is not technically a list; it's syntactically something that doesn't fit the rules. To `lsearch` within it, you first need to split the line into words. The simplest method is to use either `split $line`, but I prefer to use `regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line` so as to not generate empty elements for sequences of two or more spaces or tabs. If you have fixed width format lines, you might be better off using a different approach (such as `scan $line "some format"`); you have to understand what your data format really is.

Comment: Complex cases may even require proper parsing, such as when a "line" can go over multiple real lines or have embedded escape sequences that need to be decoded. It's all very dependent on the details.